# Updated function in NestJS service file returning results of old function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs

It seems my code isn't being updated for some reason.  Inside of my service file I created a function which originally looked like this.

```
getSampleData(): {message: string}{ return {message: 'Sample Data'}; }
```

After running `firebase serve --only functions` I successfully received the expected object.  I decided to take it a step farther and begin querying data in my database and changed the function to this.

```
getSampleData(){ return db.collection('product_index_list').get(); }
```

I restarted the server and am still receiving the `{message: 'Sample Data'}` object from the `getSampleData()` function even though I completely re-wrote the function.  I even tried running `npm run build` all over again thinking maybe it would update something but am still getting that response.  Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Try deleting the dist folder. Even with `npm run build` I've run into it not building code "it" believes hasn't changed.

Comment: What do you mean by "I restarted the server"?

Comment: @vitooh I mean I pressed `ctrl + c` and re-ran `firebase serve --only functions`.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I deleted the folder and re-ran `npm run build` but now it won't load.  I see one error saying it can't find `main.js` in the destination which is where my `main.ts` file is located.  Then it says it wasn't able to load my functions file and suggests running `npm run build` in the `functions` folder, which I get a whole list of errors.